# Twilio Autopilot: How to pull data from Airtable and return results to user?

Tags: twilio

I'm using Collect in the first Autopilot task to get the date from the user (i.e. Jan 31, 2019). Then I am trying to use that variable (date) to search an Airtable database for that specific row. I want to return the results of that row to the user ("on Jan 31 the Main Theater is playing this movie, the Other Theater is playing...).

My Airtable Get code is below, but I am unsure how to assign the returned data to variables that I can read back to the user.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 
'apikey'}).base('basekey');

base('Blockouts').find('recbGHAQopLQdCOHK', function(err, record) {
if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
console.log(record);
});
}
```

and here's the output that Airtable will send back:

```
{
    "id": "recbGHAQopLQdCOHK",
    "fields": {
        "Date": "2019-02-02",
        "Main Theater": "Star Wars",
        "Other Theater": "Avengers"
    },
    "createdTime": "2019-02-02T21:21:48.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

If your Airtable Get code is not there already, it should go in a Twilio function ([which supports Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/npm-support-for-twilio-functions.html))! that is pointed at an Autopilot task whose `actions` code has something like this:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": {
                "uri": "https://your-twilio-function-path.twil.io/airtable-or-whatever-if-this-is-your-path"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in your Twilio function/Airtable Get code, you should modify your [Twilio Response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#constructing-a-response) object to accept all requesting origins and have that look something like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let response = new Twilio.Response();
    let headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    var responseObject = {"actions":[
                     { "say": "Try again" } 
                     ]};
    response.setHeaders(headers);
    var Airtable = require('airtable');
    var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'apikey'}).base('basekey');
    base('Blockouts').find('recbGHAQopLQdCOHK', function(err, record) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
        console.log(record);

    }).then(res => {
       var date = res.data[0].fields.date;
       responseObject = {"actions":[
            { "say": date } 
            ]};
       callback(null, responseObject);
    });
};
```

I have not tested this code with your Airtable output (famous last words of a programmer), but used almost exactly the same code when making an Axios request to an API where I saved some of the data returned from that call in a variable, so it should be similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @lizziepika! Sorry, I am new to this and still trying to figure it out. My Airtable Get code is in a function, and I have a task that is redirecting to that function. I added the code you suggested to my Function (I can't paste it here for some reason) but I am getting an error message "then is not defined"

Comment: ah sorry about that, left out some code--just modified it

Comment: Thanks again @lizziepika I tried the new code and there was a syntax error. I fixed that error but now I'm getting this error from the function: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"